# How to check whether HttpServletRequest contains the key in Java (Using spring boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) request;

if (httpReq.getHeader("device").equals("web1")) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

I want to know how can I check whether the key `"device"` exists in the request header?

Note : Don't want to use `getHeaderName` which returns an enumeration of all the header names this request contains and iterate through it.

`getParameterMap().containsKey("device")` is not working here.

Comment: Why can't you use `getHeader("device")`  and see if it is null?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the JavaDoc for [`HttpServletRequest.getHeader(String name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader(java.lang.String)):

> If the request did not include a header of the specified name, this
>   method returns `null`.

So a basic null check is sufficient:

```
boolean deviceHeaderExists = httpReq.getHeader("device") != null;
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading between the lines a little, if you're looking to accept a mandatory `device` header then you can code that up with annotations in your REST call. Example:

```
@GetMapping("/something")
public void doSomething(@RequestHeader("device") @NotNull String deviceName) {
  // your logic here
}
```